# Canvas pinch to zoom issue (pivot point)

Tags: android, graphics, drawing, android-canvas, android-view

I'm drawing lines on a custom view and added pan and zoom functionality.
The problem is that when I zoom in with two fingers the middle points gets calculated right but when I do `matrix.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, midX, midY`), the canvas jumps (translates) to the `midX` and `midY` which it was before.

Let me get this straight:

I initialize the mid point between my fingers with 0/0. As soon as the second Pointer is on the screen I calculate the mid point and invalidate the onDraw. Then the drawing jumps (translates) to the last known mid point and starts to zoom in.
I don't want the drawing to be translated to the mid point rather than just zoom to the selected mid point.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

**onDraw method**

```
private float startX = 0f;
private float startY = 0f;

private float translateX;
private float translateY;

private float previousTranslateX = 0f;
private float previousTranslateY = 0f;

private float midX = 0f;
private float midY = 0f;
...

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    cx = canvas.getWidth();
    cy = canvas.getHeight();

    mat.reset();

    canvas.save();

    int count = 0; 

    mat.postScale(scaleFactor, -scaleFactor, midX, midY);           
    mat.postTranslate(translateX, translateY);

    canvas.setMatrix(mat);

    // draw stuff here...

    canvas.restore();
}
```

**onTouch method**

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        mode = DRAG;
        startX = event.getX() - previousTranslateX;
        startY = event.getY() - previousTranslateY;

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
            mode = ZOOM;
        } else {
            translateX = event.getX() - startX;
            translateY = event.getY() - startY;
        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

            mode = NONE;
            getMidPoint(event);

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        mode = NONE;
        previousTranslateX = translateX;
        previousTranslateY = translateY;

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

        mode = DRAG;
        previousTranslateX = translateX;
        previousTranslateY = translateY;

        break;
    }

    detector.onTouchEvent(event);

    if ((mode == DRAG) || mode == ZOOM) {
        invalidate();
    }

    return true;
}
```

**calculation of mid point**

```
private void getMidPoint(MotionEvent event) {

    //get offset screensize -> canvas
    int offX = sx-cx;
    int offY = sy-cy;

    //get finger coordinates relative to offset
    f1x = event.getX(0)+offX;
    f1y = event.getY(0)+offY;
    f2x = event.getX(1)+offX;
    f2y = event.getY(1)+offY;

    midX = (f1x + f2x)/2;
    midY = (f1y + f2y)/2;

    //because my points are in a local coordinate system the 
 screen coordinates need to be mapped to current canvas matrix
    Matrix m = new Matrix(mat);
    m.invert(m);
    float[] touch = new float[] { midX, midY };
    m.mapPoints(touch);
    midX = touch[0];
    midY = touch[1];
}
```

Here are some pictures:
This is when the activity starts. The red dot marks the 0/0 position of the initialized mid point

[image]

As soon as a put my fingers where the blue dots are and start zooming:

[image]

this will be the result. This happens as soon as I start to zoom.

[image]

I'd really appreciate if someone has an answer for me! Thanks in advance.